# Is the use of the construction 'May I have you...' to begin a request unnatural?

Tags: phrase-request, idiomatic-language

Is the use of the construction 'May I have you...' to begin a request unnatural?

I have been using this construction for quite some time, what with 'May you...' not being an appropriate beginning to a request. What are the alternatives I could possibly use?

Google Ngrams lists such examples of the pattern as these, from the 60s onwards:

> May I have you rise so that you may be sworn?
> May I have you come look at it for your opinion, as to its authenticity?
> May I have you comment to this statement, again reading from the memorandum of June 28...

But only three results there seems to mark this pattern as rare at best, and I am not too convinced in regard to its naturality.

Comment: In the UK, saying 'May I have you _do something_' would be regarded as weird.

Comment: But "May I ask you to..." would be possible.

Answer (score 3):

These are not impossible (but odd, especially #2), but the simplest (and so best) way to make request is the word "Please":

> Please rise so you may be sworn
>
> Please come and look at it...
>
> Please comment <s>to</s> on this statement...

There are lots of ways to request something politely:

> Could you rise?  Would you rise? Could I ask you to rise?

Answer (score 0):

While it's not unheard of, it's not the most natural usage. And if one were to choose it, it has some connotation of being a gentle way of compelling someone rather than entreating a favor. A secretary might hand you a form and say "Could I have you sign this, please," and the context is that you are required to do so, but the request is polite. If you wanted to borrow money from your parent, you wouldn't say "Could I have you give me $100"; it would seem like an arrogant way of framing a request for a favor.

Note, I've used "could" rather than "may" for these examples as the more idiomatic choice.